# How can I random an ArrayList with dispersion?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to do an application which set a game plan for a tournament.

I have a method:

```
public List<Match> creerMatchsTousContreTous(List<Equipe> lEquipe) {
        List<Match> lMatch = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lEquipe.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < lEquipe.size(); j++) {
                Match match = new Match();
                match.setEquA(lEquipe.get(i));
                match.setEquB(lEquipe.get(j));
                lMatch.add(match);
            }
        }
        return lMatch;
    }
```

This method receid a list of Teams. Each one must to play which each others. This return a list of plays (Match).

I want now to random the plays. I need that a Team A who plays the first Play not play the next one. And so more.

I use:

```
Collections.shuffle(lMatch);
```

But that ramdom the list of plays and it is possible that a tema play two successive plays.

How can I achieve that?
Thanks
Best Regards

EDIT:

EXAMPLE:

The method return a list of games:

1. TEAM 1 : TEAM 2
2. TEAM 2 : TEAM 3
3. TEAM 1 : TEAM 3
4. TEAM 4 : TEAM 3
5. TEAM 2 : TEAM 4
6. TEAM 4 : TEAM 3

creerMatchsTousContreTous() return in this example a list with 6 values. But here for example, in the first game, TEAM 2 is playing, in the second game he is also playing, and this mustn't be.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a boolean variable, such as justPlayed or hasPlayed, to the Team class. This variable would track if a particular team has just played in a game.

```
Collections.shuffle(lMatch); // get two random teams using shuffle
while(Match.Team1.getHasPlayed() == True or Match.Team2.getHasPlayed() == True){
    Collections.shuffle(lMatch); // try to find different teams
}

lMatch.play(); // you've found two teams, so now you can call your play method

for(Team t:lEquipe){             // go through the list of teams and
    t.setHasPlayed(false);       // reset the rest each team's boolean
}
Match.Team1.setHasPlayed(true);
Match.Team2.setHasPlayed(true); // set the boolean to true at the end of the turn
//
```

This is obviously pseudocode, since I don't know your implementation of Match and Team. Still, consider using the boolean instance field and checking if it has been modified in the previous turn.

Comment: I added an example in the question. lMatch is a list of games.

Comment: Basically, the implementation I provided above should still work. You should create a boolean variable in the team class. This variable determines if a team is eligible to play in a game. Since you already know how to create the lMatch list, all that's left is to check if either of the two randomly selected teams played in the previous game.

Answer (score 0):

The one below is a recursive approach. I think it can provide solution in a faster way than one suggested by @Sonedring, as constraint is applied after every randomization.

It is also safer for a corner case where you have less than 4 teams. In the corner case you will not find a solution and you don't to run an endless loop.

Hope this helps.

```
public static void randomize(List<Match> matches) {
    List<Match> randomizedList = new ArrayList<>();
    int numberOfAttempts = 256;

    // tmpSubList is a temporary list that contains all matches
    // (excluding unwanted) after n-th iteration (randomization).
    List<Match> tmpSubList = new ArrayList<Match>(matches);
    while (matches.size() > 0) {

        // if tmpSubList contains - it means there is no match that can be added.
        // Need to restart randomization algorithm.
        if (tmpSubList.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Restarting algorithm.");

            if (--numberOfAttempts == 0) {
                throw new ArithmeticException("Could not find solution.");
            }
            // Need to restart:
            matches.addAll(randomizedList);
            tmpSubList.addAll(randomizedList);
            randomizedList.clear();
        }

        int randomIndex = (int) (tmpSubList.size() * Math.random());

        Match match = tmpSubList.remove(randomIndex);
        matches.remove(match); // remove also from the main list;
        randomizedList.add(match);

        Equipe lastTeam1 = match.getEquA();
        Equipe lastTeam2 = match.getEquB();

        tmpSubList.clear();
        matches.stream()
            .filter( x -> !x.getEquA().equals(lastTeam1) && !x.getEquB().equals(lastTeam1) )
            .filter( x -> !x.getEquA().equals(lastTeam2) && !x.getEquB().equals(lastTeam2) )
            .forEach( x -> tmpSubList.add(x));
    }
    matches.addAll(randomizedList);
}
```